# Regression model for analyzing data in multiple countries and over several years (simpsons paradox in multiple regression)?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression

Let's say i have this data for the years 1990-2020, for 20 different countries:

(the variables are just made up)

Dependent variable
Foreign direct investment inflow (FDII)

Indendent variables:
Poverty rate (PR)
Government subsidies (GS)
Tax rates (TS)

I had an exercise in class and the method demonstrated there was just to make a multiple regression model (ie. in R would be lm(FDII ~PR+GS+TS)), but however, it seems like this method would miss out on the relationships between the variables within each country. What if the relationship between the variables is negative/positive at country level, but reverses when countries are combined?

Comment: What you're talking about are known as **interactions**, you specify them as art of the `formula` you pass to `lm`.  Simple answer is change all the `+` to `*` in your formula see the details section of `lm` which says in part "Models for lm are specified symbolically. A typical model has the form response ~ terms where response is the (numeric) response vector and terms is a series of terms which specifies a linear predictor for response. The specification first*second indicates the cross of first and second. This is the same as first + second + first:second."